# Hyperref and theoremref conflict?

Tags: hyperref, theorems, incompatibility

I initially thought that this problem was with Unicode characters, but reducing the file led to the MWE below which has none, so it seems that `theoremref` and `hyperref` don't like each other. Consider:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{theoremref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
\thlabel{vmezofelint}
Sample text
\end{theorem}
Sample text (see \thref{vmezofelint} ) .
\end{document}
```

It produces an error message saying

```
File ended before scanning use of \Hy@setref@link.
```

My question is: does anyone know a fix, or a simple workaround for this bug? One that requires few changes to the code?

**UPDATE:** The problem no longer exists with the latest version of `theoremref.` See [the maintainer's answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115616/21963).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn’t aware of this discussion, however since someone else recently complained about the incompatibility of the two packages, I’ve updated the theoremref package to add support for hyperref. It should be available through CTAN shortly.

Comment: I have the latest TexLive and still appears (for me) the error written by @marczellm

Comment: If I add the `memhfixc` package the errors change to `Undefined control sequence` for `\thlabel`

Comment: Ok. I solved this adding the packages in order: `hyperref`, `memhfixc` and `theoremref`.

Comment: Hmm. I have no experience with memoir or memhfixc so I may be missing some subtle problem, but for me it at least compiles successfully with the packages in arbitrary order (though the documentation of memhfixc requests it to be loaded after hyperref).

Comment: Well, with `article` class works (for me) only with the order showed above.

Comment: But `memhfixc` is a patch for `hyperref` to work with the `memoir` class. Why would you use it with `article`?

Comment: Is a mystake, I was using `memoir` class with article `option`

Answer (score 9):

Just don't use `theoremref`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{vmezofelint}
Sample text
\end{theorem}
Sample text (see \autoref{vmezofelint}).
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Expanded definition

One can set up a new theorem defining command, so the necessary steps to get the `\autoref` right are made once and for all.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse,aliascnt,hyperref,bookmark}

\NewDocumentCommand{\xnewtheorem}{m o m}
 {%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {\newtheorem{#1}{#3}}
   {%
    \newaliascnt{#1}{#2}%
    \newtheorem{#1}[#1]{#3}%
    \aliascntresetthe{#1}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1autorefname\endcsname{#3}%
   }%
 }

\xnewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\xnewtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{vmezofelint}
Sample text
\end{theorem}
Sample text (see \autoref{vmezofelint}).
\begin{corollary}\label{cor}
Sample text
\end{corollary}
Sample text (see \autoref{cor}).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've changed it, but now, given that my numerous theorem environments all share the same counter (I don't like two entities with the same number), I had to add 3 more lines for each `\newtheorem`:
`\newcommand{\<name>autorefname}{<Name>}`
`\newaliascnt{<name>}{theorem}`
`\aliascntresetthe{<name>}`

That's tedious!

Comment: @marczellm I've added a way to define an `\xnewtheorem` command, so all you need is to change `\newtheorem` into `\xnewtheorem`

Comment: Why is the `bookmark` package needed in this case? Also, have you considered writing a package with all these useful hacks and submitting it to CTAN? I always feel that there should be a "canonical" way of solving these problems other that copy-pasting a 20-line hack into the preamble.

Comment: @marczellm `bookmark` is just a convenience, because it manages bookmarks better than the default method used by `hyperref`. The code is there, if you want; I don't believe very much in automatic references.

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to use the `cleveref` package and its `\cref` command instead of the `hyperref` package's `\autoref` command, the following method may be all you need (using @egreg's MWE - many thanks!):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref}
  % nameinlink and capitalize options used to emulate
  % appearance of output of \autoref command
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{vmezofelint}
Sample text
\end{theorem}
Sample text (see \cref{vmezofelint}).
\begin{corollary}\label{cor}
Sample text
\end{corollary}
Sample text (see \cref{cor}).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a very good solution indeed! No need to `RenewDocumentCommand` and all the hacking. Unfortunately I'm writing in Hungarian and `cleveref` typesets all the references using their environment name, not the display label.
(My environments are defined this way:
`\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Következmény}` but `cleveref` still prints "lásd Corollary 2" instead of "lásd Következmény 2" and I want to keep all code English.)