# Different numbering scheme per chapter

Tags: numbering, theorems

I would like to change the numbering scheme for my theorems per chapter. That's because I have smaller and bigger chapters. Bigger chapters need subsections for proper structuring, and so my theorems are numbered within subsections. For smaller chapters there won't be any subsections so I would like to have my theorems numbered within sections. (That means one less number).

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

## Chapter 1.

### Section 1.1.

#### Subsection 1.1.1.

**Theorem 1.1.1.1.**
**Theorem 1.1.1.2.**

## Chapter 2.

### Section 2.1.

**Theorem 2.1.1.**
**Theorem 2.1.2.**

How can I do that?

MWE: (randomize section titles and theorem body text as you please)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\begin{document}
\chapter{}
\section{}
\subsection{}
\begin{theorem}\end{theorem}
\chapter{}
\section{}
\begin{theorem}\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Note: egreg's answer includes a version incorporating the hack he gave me [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82123/hyperref-and-theoremref-conflict).

Comment: It would be great if you could include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that produces the above output as it currently stands (without the adjustable/relative number of your theorems) for the community to have something to start with. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What you've added is *not* a MWE for what you have in mind. In the question of yours that you removed the link to there's *much* more involved; the problem with the simple MWE could be solved quite easily, but this wouldn't take care of `\autoref` and friends.

Comment: @egreg And what's the quite easy solution to the reduced problem? (Or is the answer to the duplicate question already the easiest possible?) Also, should I add the link back?

Comment: I added the simplified version, which is along the same lines. I feel that the old question *should* be linked again.

Comment: I found a very easy solution which uses the `chngcntr` package and appropriate `\counterwithin` commands before the beginning of a chapter. It is not automatic as the answer below but requires fewer and clearer code. Do you think this has drawbacks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If *all* theorem-like environments share this numbering system, then the following should work. Each `\snewtheorem` declarations defines *two* theorem-like environments and another environment; the "subsection" related theorem-like environment is chosen if the counter value `\subsection` has a positive value. So all theorems should be stated under a section or a subsection, but this seems what you need.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\snewtheorem}{m o m}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {
    \newtheorem{sec#1}{#3}[section]
    \newtheorem{subsec#1}{#3}[subsection]
   }
   {
    \newtheorem{sec#1}[sec#2]{#3}
    \newtheorem{subsec#1}[subsec#2]{#3}
   }
  \newenvironment{#1}
   {\ifnum\value{subsection}>0
      \csname subsec#1\expandafter\endcsname
    \else
      \csname sec#1\expandafter\endcsname
    \fi}
   {\ifnum\value{subsection}>0 
      \csname endsubsec#1\expandafter\endcsname
    \else
      \csname endsec#1\expandafter\endcsname
    \fi}
}

\snewtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\snewtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Long}
\section{First}
\subsection{A}
\begin{lem}[Big]\label{insubsec}
This is a big lemma.
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}[Big]
This is a big theorem.
\end{thm}

\subsection{B}
\begin{lem}
This is a lemma.
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\chapter{Short}
\section{First}
\begin{lem}[Big]
This is a big lemma.
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}[Big]\label{insec}
This is a big theorem.
\end{thm}

\section{Second}
\begin{lem}
This is a theorem.
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\ref{insubsec}

\ref{insec}

\end{document}
```

---

An extension of the `\xnewtheorem` I defined time ago for a question you posed about supporting `hyperref` and `\autoref` can be like this.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm,xparse,aliascnt,hyperref,bookmark}

\NewDocumentCommand{\xnewtheorem}{m o m}
 {%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {%
    \newtheorem{sec#1}{#3}[section]%
    \newtheorem{subsec#1}{#3}[subsection]%
   }
   {%
    \newaliascnt{sec#1}{sec#2}%
    \newtheorem{sec#1}[sec#1]{#3}%
    \aliascntresetthe{sec#1}%
    \newaliascnt{subsec#1}{subsec#2}%
    \newtheorem{subsec#1}[subsec#1]{#3}%
    \aliascntresetthe{subsec#1}%
   }
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname sec#1autorefname\endcsname{#3}%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname subsec#1autorefname\endcsname{#3}%
  \newenvironment{#1}
   {\ifnum\value{subsection}>0
      \csname subsec#1\expandafter\endcsname
    \else
      \csname sec#1\expandafter\endcsname
    \fi}
   {\ifnum\value{subsection}>0 
      \csname endsubsec#1\expandafter\endcsname
    \else
      \csname endsec#1\expandafter\endcsname
    \fi}
 }

\xnewtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\xnewtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Long}
\section{First}
\subsection{A}
\begin{lem}[Big]\label{insubsec}
This is a big lemma.
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}[Big]
This is a big theorem.
\end{thm}

\subsection{B}
\begin{lem}
This is a lemma.
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\chapter{Short}
\section{First}
\begin{lem}[Big]
This is a big lemma.
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}[Big]\label{insec}
This is a big theorem.
\end{thm}

\section{Second}
\begin{lem}
This is a theorem.
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\autoref{insubsec}

\autoref{insec}

\end{document}
```

[image]